# Haproxy redirection to multiple subdomains (cookies problem?)

Tags: linux, redirect, haproxy

I have only public IP which I want to use with multiple webservers so I'm trying to setup haproxy that will only redirect traffic from multiple subdomains to these servers with ssl passthrough no termination or balancing.
I have a config file which partially works.
Webbrowser for subdomain1 opens website that is located on a.a.a.a, for subdomain2 b.b.b.b
and here interesting thing for subdomain3 and subdomain4 it will open every time either c.c.c.c or d.d.d.d it depends which one was called first.
What came to my mind is that websites on sub1 and sub2 don't use cookies and sub3 and sub 4 do. I'm wondering if it has something to do with sticky sessions? Is there any way to fix it? Am I doing something wrong? Can anyone help please?

```
global
    log /dev/log    local0
    log /dev/log    local1 notice
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin expose-fd listeners
    stats timeout 30s
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon

    # Default SSL material locations
#   ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
#   crt-base /etc/ssl/private

    # Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
    # For more information, see ciphers(1SSL). This list is from:
    #  https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/
    # An alternative list with additional directives can be obtained from

    ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
    ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3

defaults
    log global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
        timeout connect 5000
        timeout client  50000
        timeout server  50000
    errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
    errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
    errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
    errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
    errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

frontend websites_80
    mode http
    option httplog
    bind *:80

    acl sub1-acl hdr(host) -i sub1.mydomain.com
    acl sub2-acl hdr(host) -i sub2.mydomain.com
    acl sub3-acl hdr(host) -i sub3.mydomain.com
    acl sub4-acl hdr(host) -i sub4.mydomain.com

    use_backend sub1_80         if sub1-acl
    use_backend sub2_80         if sub2-acl
    use_backend sub3_80         if sub3-acl
    use_backend sub4_80         if sub4-acl

frontend websites_443
    bind *:443
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
    tcp-request content accept if { req_ssl_hello_type 1 }

    acl sub1-acl        req.ssl_sni -i sub1.mydomain.com
    acl sub2-acl        req.ssl_sni -i sub2.mydomain.com
    acl sub3-acl        req.ssl_sni -i sub3.mydomain.com
    acl sub4-acl        req.ssl_sni -i sub4.mydomain.com

    use_backend sub1_443        if sub1-acl
    use_backend sub2_443        if sub2-acl
    use_backend sub3_443        if sub3-acl
    use_backend sub4_443        if sub4-acl

# 80

backend sub1_80
    balance roundrobin
    server sub1 a.a.a.a:80 check

backend sub2_80
    balance roundrobin
    server sub2 b.b.b.b:80 check

backend sub3_80
    balance roundrobin
    server sub3 c.c.c.c:80 check

backend sub4_80
    balance roundrobin
    server sub4 d.d.d.d:80 check

# 443

backend sub1_443
    mode tcp
    balance roundrobin
    option ssl-hello-chk
    server sub1 a.a.a.a:443 check

backend sub2_443
    mode tcp
    balance roundrobin
    option ssl-hello-chk
    server sub2 b.b.b.b:443 check

backend sub3_443
    mode tcp
    balance roundrobin
    option ssl-hello-chk
    server sub3 c.c.c.c:443 check

backend sub4_443
    mode tcp
    balance roundrobin
    option ssl-hello-chk
    server sub4 d.d.d.d:443
```

Comment: which version of haproxy do you use `haproxy -vv`?

Comment: Hi, haproxy/stable,now 1.8.19-1+deb10u3 amd64